# NestJS - Default (wildcard) route?

Tags: express, router, nestjs

In my Angular app, if I load the home page `/` and then navigate to, say, `/products`, it works fine (it's a lazy-loaded module). But if now I reload the page, the browser makes a `GET /products` call to the server, which results in a 404.

The solution is to send `index.html` and the Angular app is back on rails. So in Express I do `app.all("*", (req,res) => { res.sendFile("index.html") })` and it works.

How to do the same thing in Nest?

There is a `@All` decorator, but each controller in a given component handles a subroute, for instance `@Controller("cats")` will match `/cats` routes, so if I add `@All` in this controller, it will match only `/cats/*`, not `*`.

Must I really create a whole separate module with a controller, just for this? That's what I did

```
@Controller() // Matches "/"
export class GenericController {

    @All() // Matches "*" on all methods GET, POST...
    genericFunction(){
        console.log("Generic route reached")
    }
}
```

And in my main module :

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ItemsModule, // Other routes like /items
        GenericModule, // Generic "*" route last
    ],
})
```

It works, but it seems overkill. Is this the way to go or is there a simpler trick?

Comment: Here good boilerplate: https://github.com/Innovic-io/angular-nestjs-rendering You can use `angular-cli` too. Since it used `angular-cli`, front app use separate `express` instance and it's already configured to handle not found requests...

Comment: Oh I have always been using Angular CLI. But what do you mean `front app use separate express instance`? Express is server-side

Comment: I mean `angular-cli` use separate express instance

Comment: But that's `ng serve`, isn't it? It's CLI's built-in server. I'm not using `ng serve`, I'm building my own server. Anyway, your answer worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right. It's CLI's built-in server used when debugging app locally. In production of course you need own server, where in your case `NestJS` is used✌

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, will be best to use `global-scoped` exception filter.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new NotFoundExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**NotFoundExceptionFilter**:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse();
        // here return `index.html`
    }
}
```

<s>Maybe it will not work, will test later</s>

Comment: This works for the most part, however - the problem is that valid routes that return 404 (like GET /items/<invalid-id> will return index.html and not the 404.

The question was how to handle non-matching routes only.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a separated `GenericModule`. However, `GenericController` is fully valid and you approach is definitely a good one. The question is rather what would you like to achieve using this generic route. If handling "Route not found" error is your requirement, a better choice is an exception filter.

Comment: What an honor. The man himself :) What I want to do is `sendFile("index.html")`. Let me explain. In my Angular app, if I load the home page `/` and then navigate to, say, `/products`, it works fine (it's a lazy-loaded module). But if now I reload the page, the browser makes a `GET /products` call to the server, which results in a 404. The solution is to send `index.html` and the Angular app is back on rails. So in Express I do `app.all("*", (req,res) => { res.sendFile("index.html") })` and it works. How to implement `GenericController` without a module? Still haven't figured that out

Comment: @JeremyThille means something like https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @JeremyThille, I think, your question can be replaced with your comment above 

Comment: That's actually true, did so, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer in 2022.

I've solved this by specifying the routes in the order I want them evaluated. In my instance I am using a fallback route to catch all requests, but if I need custom processing I want to create a route which superceeds the fallback route.

However, in defining a catchall route `/api/:resource` in the AppController, I found the fallback route would overwrite all other routes.

My solution to this is to define the fallback route in it's own module and ensure that it is appended to the list of modules. This way it is created last and will only catch what falls through.

**#router.ts**

```
import {RouterModule} from '@nestjs/core/router';
import {ContentBlockModule} from './content_block/content_block.module';
import {FallbackModule} from './fallback/fallback.module';

const APIRoutesWithFallbackRoute = RouterModule.register([
  {
    // This lets me avoid prepending my routes with /api prefixes 
    path: 'api',
    
    // Overload the /api/content_blocks route and foward it to the custom module
    children: [
      {
        path: 'content_blocks',
        module: ContentBlockModule,
      },
    ],
  },
  { //Fallback Route catches any post to /api/:resource
    path: 'api',
    module: FallbackModule,
  },
]);
```

**#app.module**
App module imports the fallback module. **Important** Ensure `FallbackModule` is the last module to be declaired or it will overwrite routes that are included after it.

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';

import {AppService} from './app.service';
import {APIRoutesWithFallbackRoute} from './APIRoutesWithFallbackRoute';
import {ContentBlockModule} from './content_block/content_block.module';
import {FallbackModule} from './fallback/fallback.module';

// APIRoutes include first, Fallback Routes prepended.
@Module({
  imports: [APIRoutesWithFallbackRoute, ContentBlockModule, FallbackModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**FallbackController**

```
import {Controller, Post, Req, Res} from '@nestjs/common';
import {defaultHandler} from 'ra-data-simple-prisma';

import {FallbackService} from './fallback.service';

@Controller()
export class FallbackController {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: FallbackService) {}

  @Post(':resource')
  fallback(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
    // return this.appService.getData();
    console.log('executing from the default fallback route');

    return defaultHandler(req, res, this.prisma);
  }
}
```

**ContentBlockController**
The content block controller, included here for completeness.

```
@Controller()
export class ContentBlockController {
  constructor(
    private readonly contentBlockService: ContentBlockService,
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  async create(
    @Body() contentBlock: content_blocks,
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ): Promise<void> {
    console.log('executing from the resource specific route');
 
    // lean on my service to do heavy business logic
    const [model, values] = await this.contentBlockService.createContentBlock(
      contentBlock,
    );

    // inject custom logic...
    const alteredRequest: CreateRequest = {
      ...req,
      body: {
        ...req.body,
        params: {
          data: values,
        },
      },
    };
   

    return createHandler(alteredRequest, res, model);
  } 
}
```

Using this system I am able to define a single route to handle 90% of the routes necessary to expose my Prisma models to my private API. And if I need custom logic I have full control.